# Incoming and Outgoing Node Connections

Tags: nodes, peers, connection

Should I be concerned that I only see "Out" connections, and not "In" connections? What does this mean? Is everything fine, or is there something I'm doing wrong?

[image: incoming and outgoing connections]

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin Core does allow inbound connections by default, but it does not advertise its own address during the initial synchronization. So if you just started running Bitcoin Core and have not caught up to the chaintip yet, that may explain why you are not seeing any inbound connections yet.

Another common reason is that your network configuration blocks access to Bitcoin Core’s port from the internet, and you may need to open the port on your router for your node.

Finally, you may have explicitly configured your node to prevent inbound connections via `--nolisten` if you followed some guide that was aiming to reduce your bandwidth usage.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am running a pruned node, does that play into it?

Comment: Generally, pruned nodes get fewer connections, but I would be surprised to learn that it were the reason that you have no incoming connections whatsoever.

Comment: okay, thanks... I will look more into the ports and whatnot